How can i find the last full weekend of a Month?
$ts1=strtotime("last saturday of november 2024"); #Timestamp1
$ts2=strtotime("+1 day",$ts1); #Timestamp2
echo "Last Saturday: ".date("d.m.Y",$ts1); #30.11.2024
echo "Last Sunday: ".date("d.m.Y",$ts2);   #01.12.2024

With the PHP code above, i get the date of the last saturday and last sunday of november 2024.
But that is not a FULL weekend, because sunday is from the first of december!
So i need the weekend before, which is a full weekend in the same month -> 23+24. November 2024.
Same problem if i need the first full weekend, which is not ok in month september 2024, because first of september is a sunday! To be a full weekend, the first weekend must be 7+8. September.
In month october, all is ok, because last full weekend is at date 26+27, so saturday and sunday are not separated.
I can't find a function in PHP doing that!
Any help?

So go and determine the last Sunday in the month then, and then go back one day from that, to get the preceding Saturday ...?

A minor mind shift example here

This question is similar to: how to find the last monday of the month. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To find the last or first full weekend of a month in PHP, you can create a function that checks whether both the Saturday and Sunday of the weekend fall within the same month. This ensures you have a "full weekend" without it spilling over into the previous or next month.
Here is the demo: Click Here
function getLastFullWeekend($month, $year) {
    $lastDayOfMonth = strtotime("last day of $month $year");

    $lastSaturday = strtotime("last Saturday", $lastDayOfMonth);
    $lastSunday = strtotime("+1 day", $lastSaturday);

    if (date("m", $lastSaturday) == date("m", $lastSunday)) {
        return [
            'Saturday' => date("d.m.Y", $lastSaturday),
            'Sunday' => date("d.m.Y", $lastSunday)
        ];
    } else {
        $lastSaturday = strtotime("last Saturday", $lastSaturday - 1);
        $lastSunday = strtotime("+1 day", $lastSaturday);

        return [
            'Saturday' => date("d.m.Y", $lastSaturday),
            'Sunday' => date("d.m.Y", $lastSunday)
        ];
    }
}

function getFirstFullWeekend($month, $year) {
    $firstDayOfMonth = strtotime("first day of $month $year");

    $firstSaturday = strtotime("first Saturday", $firstDayOfMonth);
    $firstSunday = strtotime("+1 day", $firstSaturday);

    if (date("m", $firstSaturday) == date("m", $firstSunday)) {
        return [
            'Saturday' => date("d.m.Y", $firstSaturday),
            'Sunday' => date("d.m.Y", $firstSunday)
        ];
    } else {
        $firstSaturday = strtotime("next Saturday", $firstSaturday);
        $firstSunday = strtotime("+1 day", $firstSaturday);

        return [
            'Saturday' => date("d.m.Y", $firstSaturday),
            'Sunday' => date("d.m.Y", $firstSunday)
        ];
    }
}

$lastFullWeekend = getLastFullWeekend('November', 2024);
echo "Last Full Weekend of November 2024: " . $lastFullWeekend['Saturday'] . " - " . $lastFullWeekend['Sunday'] . "\n";

$firstFullWeekend = getFirstFullWeekend('September', 2024);
echo "First Full Weekend of September 2024: " . $firstFullWeekend['Saturday'] . " - " . $firstFullWeekend['Sunday'] . "\n";

